# Uncaught TypeError: $rootScope.$on is not a function in Connectivity Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app which needs to work in offline mode. I am getting the following error when I start my app. Why is this happening - what should i do next?

I need offline mode to work to get it through the app store. In particular i have a google maps location drop down which needs to be disabled offline.

```
services.js:392 Uncaught TypeError: $rootScope.$on is not a function
```

here is my code.

```
})*/
  .factory('ConnectivityMonitor', ['$ionicPopup', function($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork, $ionicPopup){

    return {
      isOnline: function(){
        if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){
          return $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        } else {
          return navigator.onLine;
        }
      },
      isOffline: function(){
        if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){
          return !$cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        } else {
          return !navigator.onLine;
        }
      },
      startWatching: function(){
        if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
            console.log("went online");
          });

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
            console.log("went offline");
            $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'No Internet Connection',
              content: 'This app requires an internet connection.'
            })
              .then(function() {
                //ionic.Platform.exitApp();
              });
          });

        }
        else {
...
        }
      }
    }
  }])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.factory('ConnectivityMonitor', ['$ionicPopup', function($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork, $ionicPopup){
```

You have mapped `$ionicPopup` to `$rootScope`.

Inject everything as string in the arrays or just write a function, like this:

```
.factory("ConnectivityMonitor", ["$rootScope","$cordovaNetwork", "$ionicPopup", function($rootScope,$cordovaNetwork, $ionicPopup){...}]);
```

or

```
.factory("ConnectivityMonitor", function($rootScope,$cordovaNetwork, $ionicPopup));
```

Comment: it's the second answer :)